# validation is not working on submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

I've created a HTML form, which takes some input values,like this:

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
            <input type="text" id="shop_name" name="shop_name" placeholder="Shop Name" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>

    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
        <input type="text" id="phn1" name="phn1" placeholder="Phone No.(Primary)" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button></center>                  
    </div>
</form>
```

And I kept some validation in javascript to validate the shop name, phone number and email id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function validate()
   {
       var shop_name=document.form1.shop_name.value;
       var email=document.form1.email.value;
       var phn=document.form1.phn1.value;

       var phnre=/^[0-9]*$/;

       var emailre = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

       if(shop_name==='')
       {
           alert("Shop Name is required.");
           return false;
       }
       if(phn==="")
       {
           alert("Mobile number is required.");
           return false;

       }

       if(!phnre.test(phn))
       {
           alert("Invalid mobile number.");
           return false;

       }
       if(!emailre.test(email))
       {
           alert("Invalid Email Id.");
           return false;

       }

       return true;

   }
</script>
```

but,it is not working on submitting the form,

Can anyone help me on this issue.

Comment: `var shop_name = document.getElementById("shop_name").value;`  and so on for others

Comment: You should read value in another way: 
`var shop_name=document.getElementById("shop_name").value;
       var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
       var phn=document.getElementById("phn1").value;`

Comment: One more thing is you are missing some syntax in there is missing " in `<div class="row>` and the same block you have missed `</div>` which appears before the `</form>`

Comment: Thank you @HubertS

Comment: @PM-Riabel i closed the <div> in my place, while copying the code, i missed it here,That is not the problem here.

Comment: @siri  you have to  mark+up-vote one answer as accepted. You can up-vote others too if they are useful thanks

Comment: @siri of course it is not the problem here and that is why I commented instead of Answering and I do not see you text editor and you have made mistake while coping the same code but only the what you showing here. While I figuring out your JS solution for I pointed out the syntax error and I assumed you have not made mistake while coping code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your html has a few errors. The main reason this is working is because your `button` has `type="button"` this should be `type="submit"`.

All in all your html should be:

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate()">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
            <input type="text" id="shop_name" name="shop_name" placeholder="Shop Name" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-sm-3 form-group">
            <input type="text" id="phn1" name="phn1" placeholder="Phone No.(Primary)" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <center>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button>
        </center>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also, `<center>` is not supported in HTML5.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @denny yes because default type is `submit`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use submit instead of button.

```
replace 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button>
with
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change button to type submit.

```js
function validate()
{
 var shop_name=document.form1.shop_name.value;// better use like var shop_name=document.getElementById("shop_name").value
    var email=document.form1.email.value;
    var phn=document.form1.phn1.value;

    var phnre=/^[0-9]*$/;

    var emailre = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if(shop_name==='')
    {
        alert("Shop Name is required.");
        return false;
    }
    if(phn==="")
    {
        alert("Mobile number is required.");
        return false;

    }

    if(!phnre.test(phn))
    {
        alert("Invalid mobile number.");
        return false;

    }
    if(!emailre.test(email))
    {
        alert("Invalid Email Id.");
        return false;

    }

    return true;

}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate();">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
<input type="text" id="shop_name" name="shop_name" placeholder="Shop Name" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>

<div class="row>
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
<input type="text" id="phn1" name="phn1" placeholder="Phone No.(Primary)" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control">
</div>
<center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button></center>                  
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read value in another way:

```
var shop_name=document.getElementById("shop_name").value;
var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
var phn=document.getElementById("phn1").value;
```

Additionally on 9 line you missed quoata after **"row**
button should be "submit":

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace input type="button" to input type="submit"

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button>
```

try whole code it should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function validate(){             

       if(document.form1.shop_name.value == ""){
       alert("Shop Name is required.");
        return false;
       }   

        var emailID=document.form1.email;  
        if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value==""))
        {
            alert("Please Enter your Email ID")
            emailID.focus()
            return false;
        } 
        var chk;
        chk = echeck(emailID.value);
        if(chk == "wrong")
        {
            emailID.value=""
            emailID.focus()
            return false;
        }

        function echeck(str) 
    {

        var at="@"

        var dot="."

        var lat=str.indexOf(at)

        var lstr=str.length

        var ldot=str.indexOf(dot)

        if (str.indexOf(at)==-1)

        {

            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")

            return "wrong";

        }
        if (str.indexOf(at)==-1 || str.indexOf(at)==0 || str.indexOf(at)==lstr){

           alert("Invalid E-mail ID")

           return "wrong";

        }
        if (str.indexOf(dot)==-1 || str.indexOf(dot)==0 || str.indexOf(dot)==lstr){

            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")

            return "wrong";

        }
         if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1))!=-1)
         {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            return "wrong";
         }
         if (str.substring(lat-1,lat)==dot || str.substring(lat+1,lat+2)==dot)
         {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            return "wrong";
         }
         if (str.indexOf(dot,(lat+2))==-1)
         {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            return "wrong";
         }
         if (str.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
         {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            return "wrong";
         }
         return "correct";                    
    }



       if(document.form1.phn1.value == ""){
        alert("Please provide phone ");
        return false;
       }   

        return true;
    }

            </script>



    <form name="form1" action="abc.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate()">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
    <input type="text" id="shop_name" name="shop_name" placeholder="Shop Name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>


    <div class="row>
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
    <input type="text" id="phn1" name="phn1" placeholder="Phone No.(Primary)" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button></center>                  
    </div>
    </form>
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you reference this script to your HTML but i expect you are putting it in an unknown place regarding the HTML itself , here are Three working ways:-

Common thing in the three ways:

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">
```

instead of

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">
```

as in the Fiddles

1. put the validate function definition in the window object:

   ```
   window.validate = function(){.......};
   ```

   [Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/elshenawy000/2uz1gvan/4/)
2. Embed the script into the HTML itself:

   ```
   <form></form>
   <script>your validate function definition</script>
   ```

   [Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/elshenawy000/ntwgn9mo/)
3. Put the script in an external file and reference it in the HTML file (Recommended)